# Ionic App Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Content -> NavController]:

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm getting an error while putting literally anything on my `constructor` component.

**I made a component of my `menu` this is my app.html:**

```
<menu-component [content]="content"></menu-component>

<ion-nav #content [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav> 
<!-- I have to maintain this line here and on the MenuComponent cause the app didn't load the content without it... Don't know why-->
```

**This is my MenuComponent:**

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">

    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let page of pages" (click)="openPage(page)">
                <ion-icon name="{{page.icon}}"></ion-icon>
                {{page.title}}
            </button>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>

</ion-menu>

<ion-nav #content [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
<!-- See same line of app.html -->
```

**This is my MenuComponent.ts:**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

/* PAGES */
import { HomePage } from '../../../pages/home/home';
import { ContactPage } from '../../../pages/contact/contact';

@Component({
    selector: 'menu-component',
    templateUrl: 'menu.component.html'
})
export class MenuComponent {

    @Input() content;

    pages: Array<{ title: string, component: any, icon: string }>;

//This doesn't work
//    constructor( private navCtrl: NavController ) {

//This does
    constructor( ) {

        this.pages = [
            { title: 'HOME', component: HomePage, icon: 'md-home' },
            { title: 'CONTACT', component: ContactPage, icon: 'ios-chatbubbles' }
        ];

    }

    openPage(page) {
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(page.component);
    }
}
```

**Also tried this variation:**

```
private navCtrl: NavController;

    constructor(navCtrl: NavController) {

        this.navCtrl = navCtrl;
```

**Lastly this is my app.module:**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';

/* PAGES */
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { ContactPage } from '../pages/contact/contact';

/* COMPONENTS */
import { MenuComponent } from '../shared/components/menu/menu.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ContactPage,
    MenuComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ContactPage,
    MenuComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    ModalUtil,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Provider: ModalUtil.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { ViewController, ModalController} from 'ionic-angular';

@Injectable()
export class ModalUtil {

    constructor( 
        private modalCtrl: ModalController,
        private viewCtrl: ViewController) {

    }

    presentModal(page: any, params?: Object) {

        let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(page.component, params);
        modal.present();
    }

    dismissModal(): void {
        this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
    }
}
```

**Still getting the error:**

[image]

**Any Help guys??**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[If a MenuToggle button is added to the Navbar of a page, the button will only appear when the page it's in is currently a root page. The root page is the initial page loaded in the app, or a page that has been set as the root using the setRoot method on the NavController.](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/menu/Menu/)

It is one of those Ionic quirks. You can't inject NavController at the root level. Try injecting NavController in your app.component.ts. You'll see a similar/same error. I usually setup my ionic-menu in app.component.ts. I'm guessing it being on a different component doesn't change the fact that it is still a root level component.

Comment: Hi Anjil. I'm sorry.. I'm really trying to understand...
 
I create a service/provider and tried to inject it on the constructor...got a similar error. I still don't get what's the problem and how to correct it :/

Comment: did you add your provider (injectable) to the list of providers in app.module.ts?

Comment: Could you please share code for your custom-provider and your app.module.ts? The question only goes over why you couldn't inject NavController to your menu component. And in the app.module.ts that is posted in question, there isn't a user created provider listed.

Comment: My app.module is already in the question, but I'll edit with the provider addition and the custom-provider :D

Comment: Where are you trying to inject the provider? Everything seems to be in order in what you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
openPage(page) {
    this.content.setRoot(page.component);
}
```

It worked for me.